# Cannot access outside variables from the jquery get function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-get

I am trying to turn csv into associative array but the $.get function does not change the outside textData variable

```
function csvToArray(filename){

var textData;
var headers = new Array(),
    dataValues = new Array();

$.get(filename, function(data){
    textData = data;
});

var dataArray = textData.split('\n');
headers = dataArray[0].split(',');

for(var i = 1; i<dataArray.length; i++){
    var thisLine = dataArray[i].split(','),
        tempArray = new Array();

    for(var j = 0; j<thisLine.length; j++){
        tempArray[headers[j]] = thisLine[j];
    }

    dataValues.push(tempArray);
}

return dataValues;

}
```

Why is textData not being set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

get is **Async**

So by the time **textData** is set , the remaining statements are already executed.

So consider moving the statements after the `get` to inside the callback, wherein the `textData` is populated and then processing can be done on it.

Comment: can you set async to false or would just making it an ajax call with async:flase be better?

Comment: @JordanSimon - Using synchronous requests is a [bad idea according to MDN](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests.html): *Note: You shouldn't use synchronous XMLHttpRequests because, due to the inherently asynchronous nature of networking, there are various ways memory and events can leak when using synchronous requests.* (That's in the context of XMLHttpRequests, but the principle still applies since that's probably what jQuery uses under the hood.)